# jQuery parseJSON

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, escaping, character

Receiving this error ("JSON.parse: unexpected character") when I try to parse a JSON validated string. It works perfectly when I remove the characters that need escaped (style="width:400px;"). What am I missing? Is there a unique way to escape characters before you use parseJSON?

```
var $cookieString = '{"youTabItems": { "youTab-001": <p style=\"width:400px;\">Welcome to my test</p>, "youTab-002": "test02Value", "youTab-003": "test03Value" }}';

var $myCookieString = $.parseJSON($cookieString);

logThis($myCookieString);
```

**Update**

I was able to get the majority of it working, until I started saving / retrieving from cookies. Right now, its cutting the content off after the semicolon...any thoughts on this? I'm using 3 functions I found on quirsmode.com for the cookie functionality (shown below).

```
        function setCookie(name, value, days) { var date, expires; if (days) { date = new Date(); date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString(); } else { expires = ""; } document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/"; }
        function getCookie(name) { var nameEQ = name + "=", ca = document.cookie.split(';'), c, i; for (i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) { c = ca[i]; while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') { c = c.substring(1, c.length); } if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) { return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length); } } return null; }
        function eraseCookie(name) { setCookie(name, "", -1); }

        var cookieObject = {"youTabItems": { "youTab-001": "<p style=\"width:400px;\">Welcome to my test</p>", "youTab-002": "test02Value", "youTab-003": "test03Value" }};
        var cookieString = JSON.stringify($cookieVal);
        setCookie('youTabItems', cookieString, 28);
```

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ is your friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var $cookieString = '{"youTabItems": { "youTab-001": "<p style=\\"width:400px;\\">Welcome to my test</p>", "youTab-002": "test02Value", "youTab-003": "test03Value" }}';

var $myCookieString = $.parseJSON($cookieString);
```

Wrap your html as a string to make the JSON valid.

**Why double slashes?**

The blackslash is the escape character in JavaScript strings. That means we have to escape it itself to create a *literal* blackslash. And we need a literal backslash as escape character in the JSON.

Example:

```
var json = '{"foo": "\\""}';
```

will create the string

```
{"foo": "\""}
```

which is valid JSON. If we only had one backslash, it would create

```
{"foo": """}
```

which is not valid.

**Notice:** This is only needed because your JSON is inside a JavaScript string. If you serve it e.g. as a HTTP response, then you only need one backslash. But whatever you use to create the JSON will escape the quotes automatically, so you should not have to deal with that.

**Update**

A better method to store the data in a cookie would be:

```
var cookieObject = {"youTabItems": { "youTab-001": "<p style=\"width:400px;\">Welcome to my test</p>", "youTab-002": "test02Value", "youTab-003": "test03Value" }};
var cookieString = JSON.stringify(cookieObject);
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the slash before quotes (unless you're escaping the slahs character itself). Just enclosing the first item is enough.

Comment: It is not only not needed, it is an error. The following `"` will be  treated as the end of the value.

Comment: Well, it depends. If you're actually creating JSON text directly in JavaScript, you'll need it, otherwise the parser will see the `"` as closing that value. http://jsfiddle.net/vSwWg/

Comment: @all: Ah right. Because it is inside a JavaScript string.... sorry :) (+1) Imo you should mention why you need the double slashes. Because this is something someone can easily forget (apparently).

Comment: But then again, I'm not sure why you'd create a JSON formatted string in JavaScript, just so you can parse it into JavaScript objects. Why not just use literals in the first place?

Comment: The double slashes fixed the issue (along with the quotes that I removed for some reason when I copy'd them here), but what exactly are the double slashes doing?

     var $cookieString = '{"youTabItems": { "youTab-001": "<p style=\\"width:400px;\\">Welcome to my test</p>", "youTab-002": "test02Value", "youTab-003": "test03Value" }}';

Comment: @Mark: It creates a literal slash in the string, which is needed to work as escape character for the JSON parser (`\\"` -> `\"`). But as patrick said, why don't you create a object directly? If you serve the JSON from somewhere else (not in JS string), you only need one slash.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Feel free to edit in your explanation for future readers to save them from trawling these comments.

Comment: Well, my larger issue is that I'm trying to store the JSON in a cookie. I'm using the Cookies jQuery plugin (http://code.google.com/p/cookies/). I'm running into issues when the plugin unserializes the cookie.

After tinkering with it, I noticed that if I removed the escaped characters it would work.

Comment: @Mark: If you create a JS object and set the HTML as string (properly escaped) and then use `JSON.stringify`, it should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Yz3DA/

Comment: Mark: I have added an example for the technique @Felix Kling was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The first item is not enclosed in quotes:

```
"youTab-001": "<pstyle=\"width: 400px;\">Welcometomytest</p>",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style=\"width:400px;\">Welcome to my test</p>
```

is it a string value? then it must be quoted