# Errors when trying to loop through an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I'm trying to access the 2 search results with are returned in a javascript array.

If checked how to do it here: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)
I then tried it based on this resultset:

```
{
    "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":2,
        "params":{
            "facet":"false",
            "fl":"id,title,friendlyurl,avatar,locpath,objectid,objecttype",
            "indent":"off",
            "q":"title_search:*castle*",
            "wt":"json",
            "defType":"lucene"
        }
    },
    "response":{
        "numFound":2,
        "start":0,
        "docs":[
            {
                "title":"castle a",
                "objecttype":1,
                "friendlyurl":"castle-a",
                "avatar":"6_887_castle-a.JPG",
                "objectid":6
            },
            {
                "title":"castle b",
                "objecttype":1,
                "friendlyurl":"castle-b",
                "avatar":"794_360_13j-castle-by-night.jpg",
                "objectid":794
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

---

```
for (var i = 0, l = data.response.numFound; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(data.response.docs[i].title);
    console.log(data.response.docs[i].objecttype);
    console.log(data.response.docs[i].friendlyurl);
}
```

I do get results returned if I call the service directly, I still receive a data=null in my Chrome console log. Why is that happening?

Here is the relevant code

```
    $("#searchfavs").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/weddingservice/searchfavoritecompany/?q=" + $("#searchfavs").val(),
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.response);
                console.log(data.response.numFound);

                for (var i = 0, l = data.response.numFound; i < l; i++) {
                    console.log(data.response.docs[i].title);
                    console.log(data.response.docs[i].objecttype);
                    console.log(data.response.docs[i].friendlyurl);
                }


            }
        });
        $(this).parent().hide('slow');
    });
```

How can I loop through my results?

Comment: @PeeHaa: s/result/response?

Comment: Yeh. Either your example dataset is lying or your code is.

Comment: `data.result.docs.length`, but your object has only `data.response.docs.length`

Comment: `data` is a string containing JSON, so you have to parse it first. Since you get an error in that step, your just JSON must be invalid somehow (but what you posted seems to be valid). `data.result` and `data.items` won't work because a string doesn't have such properties. You should read the linked question more carefully ;) And don't forget to do `console.log(data)`, `console.log(data.response)` etc to see which properties the object actually contains.

Comment: *Ah:* You cannot copy and paste the JSON and put it in a string. You have to escape each ``\``, i.e. `"fq":"userid:\"C325D42C-A777-4275-BDD2-D7810A8AB9AB\""` has to be `"fq":"userid:\\"C325D42C-A777-4275-BDD2-D7810A8AB9AB\\""` inside the string.

Comment: @FelixKling:  I now worked around adding the JSON to a JS string literal and wanted to work directly on the data. You can see it live here: toptrouwen.nl/test2.aspx. If you type 'tic' in the box and exit the input (onblur) a request will be made. Even though I do get results if I call the service directly, I still receive a data=null in my Chrome console log. Any ideas? :) Thanks!

Comment: Remove the linedata = $.parseJSON(data); from your code. Your data is already a json object. When you parse data, result is invalid. There is some parsing problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data` is **NOT** JSON. Its [JS object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation) already, as you have passed `dataType: 'json'`. So you dont need to parse it again using `data = $.parseJSON(data);`

From [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

> **dataType** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   **Type**: String
>
> > The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:
> >
> > "**json**": **Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object**. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

---

Also `data` does not contain any `items`. It contains `response`. For convenience the number of found items is in `data.response.numFound` already. So you can loop like this

```
for (var i = 0, l = data.response.numFound; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(data.response.docs[i].title);
    console.log(data.response.docs[i].objecttype);
    console.log(data.response.docs[i].friendlyurl);
}
```

Also note, I just found that your JSON is malformed. JSON must be valid to make this work. Carefully try to understand the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875225/errors-when-trying-to-loop-through-an-array-with-javascript/18875395#comment27856017_18875395) @FelixKling made.

Comment: But it doesn't fix the issue _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C_. parseJSON seems unhappy with `userid:\"C325D42C-A777-4275-BDD2-D7810A8AB9AB\"`. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/45zcz/

Comment: @MathieuImbert: exactly. I corrected my code like shiplu suggested, but now I still receive the 'Unexpected token C' error.

Comment: @Flo: If you put the JSON in a JS string literal, you have to escape each occurrence of ``\``. The JSON itself is valid, but putting it in a JS literal makes it invalid.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167852/jquery-parsejson for similar problem

Comment: @Flow I get `{"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"` from your service

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: sorry for my late reply, I didn't receive a SO notification somehow. The 401 error should now be fixed. Could you try again? Thanks!

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: any idea what it can be?

Comment: @Flo just remove `data = $.parseJSON(data);` and it'll work. Se my updated answer for detail information

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

Your response data is already an object so no need to parse. When you try to parseJson it returns null.

```
data = $.parseJSON(data); //remove this line which is returning null and try
console.log(data);
console.log(data.response);
console.log(data.response.numFound);
```